# Can I re-lock an element of a page in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, shortcuts, master-page

Is there a way I can re-lock an unlocked element (<kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>shift</kbd> + click) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "re-lock" you seem to actually mean "reapply the master page".

You can do that by first deleting anything you've chosen to override (command/shift/click) then drag the master page back to the page you are working on in the `Pages Panel`.

This will re-apply the master page and all it's elements. If you fail to delete any existing overrides, you will have duplicate items appearing on the page.

Comment: ok, thank you, but my problem is for example when I want to change color of just one pagenumber I must unlock it, right, and than I want to "re-lock" because I need to change appearance of all pagenumbers (font, size, etc). Is it possible ?

Comment: If items change on each page, they should not be placed on master pages. Master pages are for elements which *do not* change on the pages.

Comment: Yeah I know, what are they for, but here is the problem i need just change color of few page numbers but after that i need to edit them generaly with all the rest page numbers you get me ? :) So is it possible or no ?